# ngb tooltip not working inside the ngFor loop angular

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am using ngb-tooltip for my project. its working well. but when i use inside the ngFor loop, it did not work

this is the code

```
    <mat-button-toggle-group name="lockers" *ngFor="let loc of availableLockers" required
                            [(ngModel)]="reservelocker.lockerCode" aria-label="Font Style">

                            <mat-button-toggle value="{{loc.lockerCode}}" ngbTooltip="Tooltip"
                                [ngClass]="{'lk-av' : loc.allocStatus=='un-alloc','lk-tr' : loc.allocStatus=='temp-alloc','lk-re' : loc.allocStatus=='alloc'}"
                                [disabled]="loc.allocStatus=='alloc'">
                                <i class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i> <em class="locker-no"> {{loc.lockerCode}} </em>
                            </mat-button-toggle>
                             
                        </mat-button-toggle-group>
```

I tested this without using ngFor. thats working. why this did not work inside the ngFor.

this is working well

```
<button type="button" ngbTooltip="test"> test </button>
```

Comment: Does it also work on a mat-button-toggle outside of an ngFor?

Comment: The problem is probably mixing of angular material and angular bootstrap components. Maybe `<mat-button-toggle>` does not support the `ngbTooltip` attribute.

Comment: @tromgy yes. i removed it and tried with material tooltip. now working. thank you